# Subtracting Series

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, series-expansion, summation

When I input the following

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m+1}x[n]-\sum_{n=0}^{m}x[n]$$

which in `InputForm` is:

```
Sum[x[n], {n, 1, 1 + m}] - Sum[x[n], {n, 1, m}]
```

it returns

$$-\sum_{n=0}^{m}x[n]+\sum_{n=0}^{m+1}x[n]$$

Is it possible to get *Mathematica* to return `x[m+1]`?

I have tried:

```
FullSimplify[
  Sum[x[n], {n, 1, 1 + m}] - Sum[x[n], {n, 1, m}],
  Element[m,Integers]
]
```

and some other minor variations of the above.  Perhaps I am asking *Mathematica* to do too much, having not defined `m` or the `x[n]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: To help people to help you, you should include your input in `InputForm` so that people can copy and paste it into a *Mathematica* notebook.

Comment: A quick cheat: `Sum[x[n], {n, 1, 1 + m}] - Sum[x[n], {n, 1, m}] /. m -> 7 /. 
 k_Integer :> k - 7 + m` evaluates to `x[1 + m]` There is nothing special about `7` you can use any positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dirty trick:

```
expr = Sum[x[n], {n, 1, m + 1}] - Sum[x[n], {n, 1, m}];
Sum[DifferenceDelta[expr, m], m]
   x[1 + m]
```